# ngModel not working when set value manually from ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, textarea, onchange, ngmodel

I have in `ts` file set textarea value manually.

Example: `element.value = 'people'`,
but `ngModel` doesn't accept a value change (Example as these two images above. ngModel not binding).

```html
<textarea id="abc" type="text" (keyup)="autosize($event)"
          class="form-control card__content-inner__body__content" placeholder=""          
          [(ngModel)]="cards[index].front" (ngModelChange)="loadValueChange($event)"
          tabindex="{{index+1}}" id="card-tiem{{index}}">
</textarea>
<!-- <span class="card__content-inner__body__content-labelText">TERM</span> -->
<h1>{{cards[index].front}}</h1>
```

[First step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVmqm.png)
[Second step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uAZc.png)

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Hey, I don't understand your problem. What do you mean by "ngModel doesn't accept a value change"?

Comment: can you update question with loadValueChange  method?

Comment: Oh sorry. Example as these two images above. ngModel not binding

Comment: I'm use loadValueChange method because i need use param after binding

Comment: `[ngModel]="cards[index].front" (ngModelChange)="loadValueChange($event, index)"` and in loadValueChange method do something like `this.cards[index].front = value`

Comment: @Kitsune66 it's working for me, thank you <3